# Can't configure virtual host in apache ubuntu

Tags: apache, ubuntu, laravel

I've tried to configure virtual host on apache for project on laravel. For this I created file in /etc/apache2/sites-available/app.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  ServerName app
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/app/public
  <Directory />
    Options All
    AllowOverride All
  </Directory>
  <Directory /var/www/html/app/public>
    Options All
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
  </Directory>
  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
  # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
  # alert, emerg.
  LogLevel warn
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
  ServerSignature On
</VirtualHost>
```

Then I've activated the host:

```
sudo a2ensite app.conf
```

And had following message in the terminal:

```
Enabling site app.
To activate the new configuration, you need to run:
  service apache2 reload
```

Then I reloaded it

Also I've modified the '/etc/hosts':

```
127.0.1.1   Alexandra
127.0.0.1   app
```

So, now when i go on **app/** in browser, it shows me folders of the project:

**Index of /**

```
app/    
laravel/    
project/    
site/
```

Now if I want to display 'welcome page', I should go to app/app/public

Where is mistake in my configuration process?

Comment: Where is laravel installed? Can you give the full path of the `public` folder?

Comment: sometimes you need to restart apache `sudo service apache2 restart`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `app.conf` should be edited to:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/app/public/app/public
```

It appears you installed laravel in `/var/www/html/app/public/app`

**UPDATE**

You probably have the default site's `DocumentRoot` set to `/var/www/html`. If this is the case, then please:

1. Install laravel in:

   `/var/www/app`
2. Define it's `DocumentRoot` as:

   `/var/www/app/public`
3. Restart apache

   `sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: laravel installed in /var/www/html/app

Comment: and in that folder there are 4 folders: app, bootstrap, vendor, public; and some files: composer.json, artisan etc.